# Is there any OSS projects that manage React / NodeJS + Express CRUD app with PostgreSQL?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mern, react-boilerplate

I have MERN ( Mongo SailsJS React NodeJS ) app. After reviewing the code, there is a quite poor quality, pages are not well thought, and each change I would have to make in the future will be hard. Besides, I may want to switch SailJS for Express, and Mongo for Postgres ( still thinking ). The only good thing about this app is that it is looking good.

So, I'm thinking about keeping the HTML / CSS stuff, and rewriting the whole app.

App is not so big, so I will spend as much time as refactoring it but it will be cleaner.

I am looking for a OSS project that make it easier, I was thinking about a project that use those techs, and my christmas list is:

- can generate CRUD operation for given models in NodeJS + Associated Unit Tests. Managing relationships between models would definitively be great.
- can generate CRUD operation for given models in ReactJS + Associated Unit Tests. Managing relationships between models for UI generation would definitively be great.
- already have authentication elements ( login / register / lostPassword + JWT / Oauth + different user profile : Admin, simpleUser, etc.)
- have some common stuff (like User model --> edit profile, upload avatar, etc.)
- Use ORM

I could have my 10 existing models generated in a dedicated UI. It would be a better start, and I would only have to port my custom screen, I don't think I would spend so much time.

I found [generator-react-fullstack](https://www.npmjs.com/package/generator-react-fullstack), it is based on [react-starter-kit](https://github.com/kriasoft/react-starter-kit) that seems pretty popular.

On the NodeJS side, I found: [hackathon-starter](https://github.com/sahat/hackathon-starter) which gives pretty things, but it doesn't seems to come with react support

I also tried to start with [awesome-javascript](https://github.com/sorrycc/awesome-javascript) repo, it's a good help, but there is too much content; difficult to figure out what are the good options.

As I come from PHP / Laravel world, I don't know much about Javascript ecosystem. Is there such a magical starting point ? Should I proceed in 2 parts, front and back?

A bit of guidance would be quite helpful to start on a good track!